# How to get the path of image with OnClick in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable

I stored a collection image paths in the `Sql` database and displayed on an `asp.net` page. And I used the following code to get path of any image that user click on it.
My problem return path of the first image with any click.
How can I solve it?

**Default.aspx**

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="200" Width="125" ImageUrl='<%#Eval ("img") %>' OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
```

**Default.cs**

```
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ViewState["img"] = dt.Rows[0]["img"].ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Do you want image path or the first image?

Comment: I want image path for each image that user click on it.

ex:

while user click on first image I need path of first image.
while user click on 10th image I need path of 10th image.

Answer (score 0):

you should filter to get related row. You can use Linq for Object and filter using where and select your field.

example- (suppose filter by column id):

```
 dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>r.Field<int>("id")==4).Select(r => r.Field<string>("img"));
```

Comment: But, `(r=>r.Field<int>("id")==4)` change by user tension

Comment: That is an example, What the key of the datatable?

Comment: OK. I knew. But, `4` is dynamic and change by user's intention

Comment: Dt.rows[0] is the first path in the collection, it should be a variable. Do you add path in listbox/combox  with datasource =dt ?

Comment: I do not use listbox/combox. I want get path of any image that clicked on it.

`DataTable dt = new DataTable();`

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable() create empty DataTable. How you fill it. What is its structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Server.MapPath("filename"). 
For more details refer : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx

Also the implementation might be different in mvc.

Answer (score 0):

as per your details looks like you only get the value of

> dt.Rows[0]["img"].ToString() it is only return first path of your image always
>   you need to use for loop for exact solution.

Comment: But, loop does not enough to exact solution. In addition this, I need retrieve path of the image which is selected by user.

Comment: ViewState["file1"]=Server.MapPath("~/FolderName/" + ImagebuttonID.FileName); use this